# Read and store values from Windows Form in Methods

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote a programme in VB to calculate the efficency of a heat exchanger with the temperature and other variables as user imput in a windows form. In VB is very simple, you just type:

```
Tcin = Val(Form1.Tempcin.Text);
Thin = Val(Form1.Temphotin.Text);
```

and the values are stored in Tcin and Thin.

But I have to translate the whole code to C# and I'm facing a lot of problems just to get the values form the text boxes in the windows form (all numerical). I have to use them in several methods as well, not only in the main form. The same happens with RadioButtons and CheckBoxes.

How do I call the variables or the "check status" of the buttons and checkboxes in the namespace and the several methods?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Form1.cs class, you can call:

**Checkbox:**

```
bool checked = this.checkBox1.Checked;
```

**Radiobutton:**

```
bool checked = this.radioButton1.Checked;
```

**Textbox:**

```
string text = this.textBox1.Text; // For text
```

- or -

```
int number = this.Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text); // For numbers
// If the textbox contains letters, there will be an error thrown (an exception)
```

Update the control names accordingly. You may have named your textbox `myTextBox` instead of `textBox1`.

This topic has to do with *controls* in C#. A button, a textbox, a checkbox, a radiobutton, a progressbar, and even a form ... these are all *controls*. This should help you with terminology if you want to Google further.

Comment: But it is still not detecting the variables. I read  here that to declare global variables a class is declared where all the variables are put inside, and then are called from that class.
But still, when I write there the variables and I try to get the values from the windows form, the text boxes are not detected. The radiobuttons and check boxes work fine, but not the textboxes. I checked the names where in accordance and no problem there. I wrote this
public const double Tcin = double.Parse(this.Tempcin.Text);
public const double Thin = double.Parse(this.Temphotin.Text);

Comment: but in the class where I write the constants, the This keyword cannot be used. it doesn't detect the text boxes. I have to fix that before moving forward in the programme...